# electron app css animation performance issue

Tags: css, electron, css-animations

I am using CSS animation inside electron app. Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvbVYV

When I open the app with the animation enabled the cpu usage is 147%

But if I comment these lines

```
-webkit-animation: progress-indef 1s linear infinite;
          animation: progress-indef 1s linear infinite;
```

The cpu usage is 13%-40% only.

I am not able to figure why the cpu usage increases by 100% by adding a simple css animation. Did anyone face the same issue in past?
Is there anything needs to be set in electron's configuration?

Thanks in advance.